# Examples of functional equations where the sought solution is bijective

Tags: reference-request, functional-equations

I am looking for a reference (or just examples) of functional equations of one or multiple variables where the solutions are sought among self-bijections of $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. Ideally, Olympiad-level or alike. An example I have in mind is this:

$$f(x + f(x)) = 3f(x).$$

Could be specific Putnam problems etc.

Comment: At [Wolfram|Functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/) you will find a lot of functions listed. You see a bijective function click on it > *Identities* > *Functional Identities* and you see some good functional equations. [E.G.](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sinh/17/01/02/0001/) $f(x + y)^4 - 2 (f(x)^2 + f(y)^2 + 2 f(x)^2 f(y)^2) f(x + y)^2 + (f(x)^2 - f(y)^2)^2 = 0$ with $f(z) = \sinh(z) \wedge z \in \mathbb{R}$. Do you mean something like that?